# How to disable saving Facebook session?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I can logout after I got token but I think it is not correct. After logging out the session is still available if I go to Facebook again.

How to disable saving Facebook session?

Comment: If you want more answers, you need to make your question more clear. Also, if you give a terrible question, you won't get any answers, so try to write more than one sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you're asking is how to login and out of Facebook without caching the session token. If that is what you are asking, us the FBLoginView. You do not need a Facebook session to use it, and it allows you to log in and out of Facebook, and most of the code is already written.
[Here is the link to the tutoiral](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial).